# jax: How do we solve the error: pmap was requested to map its argument along axis 0, which implies that its rank should be at least 1, but is only 0?

Tags: python, neural-network, jax, pmap

I'm trying to run this [simple introduction to score-based generative modeling](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SeXMpILhkJPjXUaesvzEhc3Ke6Zl_zxJ?usp=sharing#scrollTo=8PPsLx4dGCGa). The code is using `flax.optim`, which seems to be moved to `optax` meanwhile (https://flax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/converting_and_upgrading/optax_update_guide.html).

I've made a [copy of the colab code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13XoMxAOkfYoFpK9-CQoh0jwk2QsNcrin#scrollTo=21v75FhSkfCq) with the changes I think needed to be made (I'm only unsure how I need to replace `optimizer = flax.jax_utils.replicate(optimizer)`).

Now, in the [training section](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13XoMxAOkfYoFpK9-CQoh0jwk2QsNcrin#scrollTo=8PPsLx4dGCGa&line=1&uniqifier=1), I get the error

> pmap was requested to map its argument along axis 0, which implies that its rank should be at least 1, but is only 0 (its shape is ())

at the line `loss, params, opt_state = train_step_fn(step_rng, x, params, opt_state)`. This obviously comes from the `return jax.pmap(step_fn, axis_name='device')` in the "Define the loss function" section.

How can I fix this error? I've googled it, but have no idea what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are passing a scalar argument to a pmapped function. For example:

```py
import jax
func = lambda x: x ** 2
pfunc = jax.pmap(func)

pfunc(1.0)
# ValueError: pmap was requested to map its argument along axis 0, which implies
# that its rank should be at least 1, but is only 0 (its shape is ())
```

If you want to operate on a scalar, you should use the function without wrapping it in `pmap`:

```py
func(1.0)
# 1.0
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `pmap`, you should operate on an array whose leading dimension matches the number of devices:

```py
num_devices = len(jax.devices())
x = jax.numpy.arange(num_devices)
pfunc(x)
# Array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36, 49], dtype=int32)
```